# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, vaadin

I have experience with Vaadin but I'm new to GWT.

I'm trying to extend the [Google Maps for Vaadin 7 add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/googlemaps-add-on), which uses a GWT wrapper for the Google Maps API, so that it can use Marker With Label from the [Google Maps utility libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) so that I can add labels to markers.

Because I want to avoid any inheritance issues with GWT, I am simply changing the [code of the original add-on](https://github.com/tjkaal/GoogleMapsVaadin7/tree/master/googlemaps) and adding a `markersWithLabel` property next to the existing `markers` property (I don't need any polymorphic behaviour anyway), so the idea is that I would have 2 sets of markers (one with labels and one without).

So I created a `GoogleMapMarkerWithLabel` class next to the existing [`GoogleMapMarker`](https://github.com/tjkaal/GoogleMapsVaadin7/blob/master/googlemaps/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/client/overlays/GoogleMapMarker.java) class, duplicating it and adding the Marker With Label specific properties.

I also created the `MarkerWithLabel` and `MarkerWithLabelOptions` in a similar way, copying and extending the original `Marker` and `MarkerOptions` from the GWT wrapper.  These indirectly extend `com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject`.

I changed the GoogleMapConnector and GoogleMapWidget classes accordingly to have the 2 sets of markers and of course rebuilt my widget set.

I'm not using these `MarkerWithLabel` and `MarkerWithLabelOptions` anywhere else, but still I get the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject
```

which normally indicates that I'm trying to use client classes at the server side.

What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**: full server-side stack trace of the root exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2836)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2562)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1427)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1262)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1123)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:414)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec$MethodProperty.find(JsonCodec.java:166)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.getProperties(JsonCodec.java:695)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encodeObject(JsonCodec.java:714)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encode(JsonCodec.java:678)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encodeObjectMap(JsonCodec.java:853)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encodeMap(JsonCodec.java:840)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encode(JsonCodec.java:651)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encodeObject(JsonCodec.java:740)
    at com.vaadin.server.JsonCodec.encode(JsonCodec.java:678)
    at com.vaadin.server.LegacyCommunicationManager.encodeState(LegacyCommunicationManager.java:112)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.encodeState(AbstractClientConnector.java:246)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.SharedStateWriter.write(SharedStateWriter.java:60)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlWriter.write(UidlWriter.java:127)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getInitialUidl(UIInitHandler.java:295)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:80)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1405)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: It seems a problem in your classpath, when do you get this error, when compiling the widgetset or in server side? can you post the entire stack trace so as we can figure-out when the class is not found.

Comment: The error is at runtime, on server side.  I'll add a stack trace later today.

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino Server side stack trace added.  I won't be able to add code from my employer but it is generally as I described.

Comment: It seems you are trying to pass from client to server some kind of object extending JavaScriptObject, which cannot live in server side. Try to replace it by primitive types.

Comment: I didn't find where I was doing that, in fact the code was similar to the regular markers implementation that was already working.  I ended up integrating Google Maps as a pure javascript component with a Vaadin wrapper (not using GWT).

Comment: Probably you have something in your ComponentState class, can you post that class to take a look?. Anyway pure javascript is ok.